# AuthenticationSection.Mode returns Windows when web.config is set to Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

So my Web.Config File has:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

in my Application_Start() i make the following calls

```
Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);            
        AuthenticationSection authentication = (AuthenticationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
        AuthenticationType = authentication.Mode;
```

The problem is that AuthenticationType ends up being Windows no matter what the value i set in the web.config file.  I need to pull this value to process the page differently depending on how it is configured and can't seem to get the right values.

Comment: Got around this issue by checking the IPrincipal  type of WindowsPrincipal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think passing null to parameter of `OpenWebConfiguration` is making it open the configuration file of the machine.

If you read the MSDN docs on this. You'll notice it says that passing null will give you the root web.config.

So you may think that's what you want. But it's not. The root web.config is actually in the .NET installation path....
usually c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[.NET VERSION]\Config

Try passing the path of the Configuration file. Use this statement in place of path to get current website path

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath)
```

this makes it sure you get the right config file every time , in any environment

Comment: Sorry to necro an old post but I have been having a similar problem.  This solution makes it throw an error about not being able to map "/".

Note that I have not yet deployed to IIS. If that was the case, I could go in and make sure there was an application at the root.  However, this is happening within the VS2010 test server setup where I don't have such an ability.

Answer (score 2):

Or just use the static `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` method which will open the config.file for the running application the code is executed it.

```
var authentication = (AuthenticationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
AuthenticationType = authentication.Mode;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx

*Retrieves a specified configuration section for the current application's default configuration.*

Comment: +1; this helped me this morning. I was seeing exceptions from `OpenWebConfiguration` under VS when running as non-admin.  If you're wanting the top-level `web.config`, this does the right thing and works when running VS as normal user, to boot.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is referring wrong web.config. Here is something you might want to try:

```
 Configuration webconfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup sysweb = (System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup)webconfig.GetSectionGroup("system.web");
        System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationSection authSection = sysweb.Authentication;
        System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationMode authmode = authSection.Mode;
```